# Alternating sum of the length of intervals

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, integers, euclidean-algorithm

Here's the problem

> For two odd $m$ and $n$, which are coprime, consider the interval $[0, mn]$ and let
> $$
> A = \{0, m, 2m, \dots , nm\} 
> \quad\text{and}\quad 
> B = \{0, n, 2n, \dots , mn\}. 
> $$
> Consider the intervals divided by the elements of $A \cup B$.
>
> Prove that the alternating sum of the lengths of these intervals is equal to $1$.

For example, for $m=3$ and $n=5$
the intervals will be
$$
[0,3],\, [3,5],\, [5,6],\, [6,9],\, [9,10],\, [10,12],\, [12,15],
$$
and $3-2+1-3+1-2+3 = 1$.

Equivalently, it is enough to prove that
$$
\sum_{p=0}^{mn-1} 
(-1)^{\left\lfloor\frac{p}{n}\right\rfloor + \left\lfloor\frac{p}{m}\right\rfloor} = 1.
$$

---

**My Attempt.**

For $m \geq 3n$ case, the intervals created by $(m,n)$ can be easily extended from the intervals created by $(m-2n, n)$.

For $m=n+2$ case, it can be proved with direct computation.

So I separated the problem into 2 cases: $n \leq m < 2n$ and $2n \leq m < 3n$.

If $n \leq m < 2n$, let $m=n+r$. Then $r$ is even.

For $n \leq m < 2n$ case, let $a_k = \bigl\lfloor\frac{kn}{r}\bigr\rfloor$. Then by direct calculation, I showed that the result is
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{r}{(-1)^{k-1}(a_k -a_{k-1}-1) 
\bigl( (2k-1)n - (a_k + a_{k-1} +1)r \bigr)}
$$
but I couldn't simplify this result...

Comment: Why do you think this is true?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Well this problem is from my friend. and I simulated the result for sufficiently large m and n...

Comment: How large, please? How did your friend come across the problem? The more you tell us, the more likely that someone will be able to help.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I checked it for all coprime odd pairs of (m,n) with 1<n<m<1000.
and my friends also trying this problem. so he doesn't know the full proof

Comment: With [Approach Zero](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Csum_%7Bp%3D0%7D%5E%7Bmn-1%7D%7B(-1)%5E%7B%5B%5Cfrac%7Bp%7D%7Bn%7D%5D%2B%5B%5Cfrac%7Bp%7D%7Bm%7D%5D%7D%7D%20%3D%201%24&p=1) you can find similar competition problems, e.g. [here](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c7h548032p3176383) and [here](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c7h530479p3027463). Hope that helps.

Comment: @BillyJoe Thanks! the second link completely solves the problem. I appreciate it